# Oracle spatial satellite view from lot and lon

Tags: oracle-spatial

I have a list of latitude and longitude values in a oracle table.

Would like to convert them into geoRaster and draw them in oracle spatial for satellite view.

Is it possible, if so could any one share me the steps.

Default saptial view gives regular map, but I need satellite view of the co ordinates

Comment: Do you mean you want to etch those points into your georaster, i.e. change the color of the pixels that contain those points ?  Or do you want to show a map  that uses your raster as background, with your points overlaid on top of it ?

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind I have lat and long points and able to pin those values in map. But I'm trying to change the way it looks. In regular google map, you will have option to switch between normal view and satellite view. Satellite view will give pictorial representation of the selected co-ordinates. In oracle spatial, it looks like the satellite view is available only for georaster data. But, I don't know how to convert my latitude, longitude values into georaster data type.

Comment: There is a bit of confusion here between data storage and maps. The raster datatype (SDO_GEORASTER) is used to store all sorts of rasters (including satellite imagery). The vector datatype (SDO_GEOMETRY) is used to store all vector data: points, lines, polygons, i.e. store locations, roads and rivers, building outlines, land parcels etc. The maps are produced by tools that read the raster data and the vector data, and combines both in a map.

Comment: Example of such tools are Oracle's own Spatial Studio. But also tools like QGIS or Geoserver. They are the ones that will turn a set of points into symbols you choose in the color and size you choose, and render them onto a map, that can be formed from one or more rasters. You do not need to generate another raster with the points. So, my question is: what GIS/mapping tool are you using with your data (raster and vector) ? Have you looked at Spatial Studio as a starting point ?